# Detect that an app launched into background state?

Tags: ios, background, uiapplicationdelegate

How do I detect that an app has launched into the background state? Needless to say regular apps cannot do this, only a small set of apps of the proper type can, and it is not an ideal situation. In particular Newsstand apps do this.

Comment: Can you give an example of an app that launches into the background? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Are you talking about something MobileSubstrate based?

Comment: VOIP app with the proper voip background modes plist key set.

Comment: @hotpaw2 - so you think this means an app that has gone into the background and will still be running? That does make more sense than one that was _launched_ into the background. Can the question be edited to reflect this if it is the case, Mithras?

Comment: And the answer to the puzzle is.... Newsstand apps do this.

Comment: Nowadays apps supporting quickreply in push notifications also start in background.

Answer (score 24):

Hard to believe nobody answered this correctly yet. From the [iOS App Progamming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4):

> To determine whether your app is launching into the foreground or
>   background, check the applicationState property of the shared
>   UIApplication object in your
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: delegate method. When the
>   app is launched into the foreground, this property contains the value
>   UIApplicationStateInactive. When the app is launched into the
>   background, the property contains the value
>   UIApplicationStateBackground instead. You can use this difference to
>   adjust the launch-time behavior of your delegate methods accordingly.

Comment: Updated link: [link] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623003-applicationstate)

Comment: this used to work but the UISceneManager messes this up. also, the scene manager loads the view even if launched into background, this shouldn't be happening at all.

Comment: @Hogdotmac I'll bite - what's UISceneManager? Did you mean some other type, or is this something outside of iOS?